# Recyclerview onBindViewHolder not working correctly Samsung API 22

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

UPDATED:

I have a tabbed activity, and inside one of the fragments, all I have is a recyclerview.

On some of the rows of the recyclerview (see code) I set the height to be zero, since I don't want these rows to be visible. I do it like this:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    DailyPointsAdapter.DailyPointsViewHolder dailyPointsViewHolder = (DailyPointsAdapter.DailyPointsViewHolder) holder;

    dailyPointsViewHolder.titleTextView.setText(finalList.get(position).getTitle());
    dailyPointsViewHolder.descriptionTextView.setText(finalList.get(position).getDescription());

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = dailyPointsViewHolder.background.getLayoutParams();

    if(finalList.get(position).getTitle().equals("No Data yet")){
        params.height = 0;
        params.width = 100;
        dailyPointsViewHolder.background.setLayoutParams(params);
    }else{
        dailyPointsViewHolder.background.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}
```

It works fine on other devices, but on my samsung galaxy API 22 the last few rows are also set to height zero. Even though the getTitle() does not equal "No data yet".

Why would this happen on this device?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: which version of RecyclerView do you use ?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

Comment: try to change recyclerView layout_height="match_parent" to  layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: @DimDim, tried that, didn't work. Thanks

Comment: It may not be a solution but you should not have app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Please update version of a library in gradle file:

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

From Android Support Library 23.2.1 update, all WRAP_CONTENT should work correctly.

Comment: This didn't change anything.